# Revenue for individual apps?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I'm relatively new to the App Store (not new to Objective-C, though) and I'm wondering how easy it is to track how much money each individual app you have in the app store is making.

I have an App in the store already, and I haven't received any sort of income statements yet so I don't know how they're split up, but I have a friend who wishes to work on my next project with me - we want to split the profits 50-50.

Say I have **two** apps in the app store, is there a way to find out how much each app is making, if they both use the same revenue models (fremium, iAds w/ IAP)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Apple software or hardware

Comment: @revolver are you serious? The title of this site is "Answers to your apple questions". iTunes connect, the main focus of this question, and it's features, are Apple software. The App Store, is Apple software. My App, is Apple software. The devices that will run my App are apple devices. How much more Apple-related could my question possibly be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. They will report and provide a way to export that date each individual sale or in-app purchase. So you will be able to break it down by app, by country, by time etc.

Answer (score -1):

Not being part of the Mac development program or iOS development program, I have never used iTunes Connect, but just off the top of my head it wouldn't make any sense if Apple was not reporting sales by individual app. The short answer is yes, they do.

There is a guide available [here](http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf) that details the information provided in Sales Reports. There is also another one within iTunes Connect.